# Write in WordPress Pages with PHP Functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to ask if there were any PHP functions to edit the content of a specific page of a WordPress Blog, naturally if I have an Account for this WordPress Blog.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find what you search on the wordpress documentation :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post